# How to set php 8.0 as default version in ubuntu server

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

For some reason, i have to install PHP 7.4 and PHP 8.0 in the same ubuntu server. By default when i install php 7.4, it shows it is the default version when use the command `php -v`.

But i want to run composer using PHP 8.0 now to install one of my application in the server. Server cant find any php version now, so i cant install my application using composer.

**How did i install PHP 8.0**

I have used `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` this repository to install latest version of 8.0 in the server, I can make it work with caddy server and even site is running fine in my testing environment. `https://caddyt.tamilchatz.com` << you can check out this URL to make sure my 8.0 is running fine in server.

Anyway i have removed PHP 7.4 from server to make sure does it help me to set 8.0 as default one, but no i can't get it to work.

```
php --version
```

[image]

Help me out to set PHP 8.0 as default version in server now. Thanks.

Comment: You need to tell apart different flavors of php, independent of the php version. THe error message you get implies that you did not install the php-cli version which is used in a shell. You need to install various packages all belonging to a php setup.

Comment: I have it installed it already, check this screenshot, i tried to remove php, just found that i have these packages are installed already. https://i.ibb.co/TcvHv77/Snap-Shot-01971.png

Comment: Type `php`, then hit tab twice. Does any other command versions show up? Sometimes it get installed as php56 or php7, and you need to alias it

Comment: That said, you might have better luck at superuser.com or https://askubuntu.com, since they deal more with linux and repositories.

Comment: Here you go, thats all i get when type 'php' and tab. https://i.ibb.co/9NHFnnN/Snap-Shot-01972.png

Comment: Both screenshots contradict each other. As if those packages were corrupted, not fully installed. Or maybe your root account's PATH variable has a very strange setting...

Comment: @JosephMiller - please edit your question and post properly-formatted text, not images of text (you've now posted links to images in a few comments, along with an image of text in the question itself). This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important.

Answer (score 5):

To update CLI version:

`sudo update-alternatives --config php`

should work for all ubuntu versions after 16.04 (18.04 and 20.04)

This is what you should see as a response:

There are 4 choices for the alternative php (providing /usr/bin/php).

```
  Selection    Path             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/php7.2   72        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/php5.6   56        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/php7.0   70        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/php7.1   71        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/php7.2   72        manual mode
```

Press  to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number and press enter to change version:

To Update version in server/browser output (you can use for all version just change version number as per requirement):

**DOWNGRADE PHP 8.0 to PHP 7.4**

```
sudo a2dismod php8.0
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo update-alternatives --config php
sudo update-alternatives --config phar
sudo update-alternatives --config phar.phar
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**UPGRADE PHP 7.4 to PHP 8.0**

```
sudo a2dismod php7.4
sudo a2enmod php8.0
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo update-alternatives --config php
sudo update-alternatives --config phar
sudo update-alternatives --config phar.phar
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
```

Comment: Sure, but for that the executables need to be present in the first place...

Comment: Also this is for shell invocations only and won't affect i.e. Apache module version